# Intellisense with many constants (nesting?)

Tags: c#, .net, constants, intellisense

**Scenario:** there is a list of string constants (over 100 now, will be more in future) which are defined like this:

```
public const string ChildA = "Child A";
public const string ChildASomeParameter = "Some parameter";
public const string ChildASomeOtherParameter = "Some other parameter";
...
public const string ChildB = "Child B"; 
public const string ChildBSomeParameter = "Some different parameter"; 
public const string ChildBSomeOtherParameter = "Some parameter";  // values are not unique
...
```

**Problem**: it's not pretty to use this with intellisense : when `ChildA` is needed you may get intellisense offering `ChildASomeParameter99999` instead. Scrolling that or typing name fully is obviously not efficient.

I had idea to move parameters into nested types, like this

```
public const string ChildA = "Child A";
public class ChildA
{
    public const string SomeParameter1 = "Some parameter 1";
    public const string SomeParameter2 = "Some parameter 2";
}
```

But then there is a compile time issue:

> The type 'MyConstants' already contains a definition for 'ChildA'

I need help (ideas) of how to deal with that issue.

My thoughts:

- put `ChildA` into another nested type? This will add overhead: `ChildA` will be used *more frequently* than any of its parameters, `using static` really shine here, having to type something like `Childs.ChildA` is not fast.
- rename something? Rename `ChildA` to something ugly `_ChildA`? Or rename nested type to something ugly? What name wouldn't be ugly then?

Maybe someone knows a better way?

Comment: e.g. public class ChildA
{
     public const string Name = "ChildA";
}

Comment: @bushed, that sounds like the best option so far. I am still hoping there are better options (something what I don't know or haven't thought about).

Comment: If the constants can not be separated and associated with specific classes, and are really just generic constants (i.e. a list of error codes or something like that), I would most likely just take the hit, and accept that there's going to be typing involved. They apparently belong together, so should be together, and at least the names are explicit and concise, if not pleasant to type. Either that, or come up with appropriate abbreviations for the repeating parts of the constants.

Comment: Apparently nameof() is considered compile-time constant. E.g. can be put in attributes. If you can get away with just property names instead of strings it might do the trick
public class A : Attribute {
    public A(string name) { }
    public const string Name = nameof(Name);
}

[A(nameof(A.Name))]
public class X { }

Comment: Do you have any performance consideration?

Comment: @dotctor, to a certain extent. Those constants are used in serial communications (usb cdc virtual serial port, baud rate: 1 Mb). Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Current` for current class?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(Constants.ChildA.Current);
    System.Console.WriteLine(Constants.ChildB.SomeOtherParameter);
    System.Console.WriteLine(Constants.ChildA.SomeParameter);

}

public static class Constants
{
    public static class ChildA
    {
        public const string Current = "Child A";
        public const string SomeParameter = "Some parameter";
        public const string SomeOtherParameter = "Some other parameter";
    }

    public static class ChildB
    {
        public const string Current = "Child B";
        public const string SomeParameter = "Some different parameter";
        public const string SomeOtherParameter = "Some parameter";
    }
}
```

Comment: `using static Constants;` to make it even better (compared to a plain list of constants). Would be really cool to avoid having that `Current`, but maybe there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx).

[Using Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=VS.90).aspx)

Like this:

```
namespace N1     // N1
{
  class C1      // N1.C1
  {
      class C2   // N1.C1.C2
      {
      }
  }
  namespace N2  // N1.N2
  {
      class C2   // N1.N2.C2
      {
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you adapt your example to my code? I don't see how namespaces are different compared to type nesting or what is the advantage of using namespaces? Where `ChildA` and `ChildASomeParameter` are defined?

Comment: I mean that namespaces make easy to use same type names, but @dotctor hase better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
public class ChildA
{
    public const string Name = "Child A"
    public const string SomeParameter1 = "Some parameter 1";
    public const string SomeParameter2 = "Some parameter 2";
}
```

Option 2 (with constrains):

```
public class ChildA
{
    public const string SomeParameter1 = nameof(SomeParameter1);
    public const string SomeParameter2 = nameof(SomeParameter2);
}
```

usage: `nameof(ChildA), nameof(ChildA.SomeParameter1)`

To elaborate on constraints:

- cannot use arbitrary strings
- `nameof` returns only top-level name. E.g. `nameof(ChildA.ChildAA.Param1) == "Param1"`

Comment: We can use "enum" instead of Option 2.

Comment: Problem is what `nameof(ChildA) != "Child A"` (note space), in reality there are values like `"Some property (A)"` (containing characters what can't be used as a member name).

Comment: @Chandru You mean instead of constant strings - that would restrict further nesting - you cannot have nested classes in enums

Comment: @Chandru, enums with strings? No we can't.

Comment: I meant like this instead of option2     public enum ChildA
    {
        ChildA,
        SomeParameter1,
        SomeParameter2
    } anyway we couldn't use this option because we need space between words.

Comment: With enums you lose nesting, also e.g. try passing Enum into a attribute constructor. You'll get CS0181 compilation error